# Perl - XML::LibXML: bad parsing performance on Apache2 default page

Tags: perl, libxml2

I was testing some code and parsing XML was included. For simple testing I requested / of my localhost and the response was my Apache2 default page.
So far, so good.

The response is XHTML and therefore XML. So I took it for my parsing (~11k of size).

```
XML::LibXML->load_xml (string => $response);
```

It takes about 16s till it finishes with no error.

If I give it an other xml-file with double the size if need 0 time.

**So...why????**

```
Apache/2.4.10
Debian/8.6
XML::LibXML/2.0128
```

**EDIT**

I need to mention that I removed the non-XML HTTP-header.

So the string starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

and ends with

```
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=88759644475809123183

Comment: Could you share the content of `$response` so that we can check it at our end?

Comment: It is the output of the Apache2 Default Page without HTTP-headers. Size ~11k. I will put a tinyupload-link in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that each time you parse the document the parser is downloading the DTD from W3C.  You could confirm this using strace or similar tools depending on your platform.

The DTD contains (among other things) the named entity definitions which map for example the string `&nbsp;` to the character `U+00A0`.  So in order to parse HTML documents, the parser does need the DTD, however fetching it via HTTP each time is obviously not a good idea.

One approach is to install a copy of the DTD locally and use that.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems you can just install the `w3c-dtd-xhtml` package which also sets up the appropriate XML catalog entries to allow libxml to find it.

Another approach is to use `XML::LibXML->load_html` instead of `XML::LibXML->load_xml`.  In HTML parsing mode, the parser is more forgiving of markup errors and I think also always uses a local copy of the DTD.

The parser also provides options which allow you to specify your own handler routine for retrieving reference URIs.

Comment: Indeed, it is the network. I did not expect that. Thanks!

Comment: To stop loading the DTD over the network, set the [`no_network`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#no_network) parser option to 1 (recommended in general) or [`load_ext_dtd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#load_ext_dtd) to 0.